# Obtain retained MQTT message

Tags: esp8266, mqtt

I’m using ESP8266 with Arduino code. Each device posts a ‘state’ and an ‘avail’ messages for a specific topic.

I wish to be able to read those retained messages and not only right after connecting and subscribe to MQTT broker.

**EDIT 1**  - Clarifications

1. I'm using Raspberry Pi Zero W as a MQTT Broker ( Local ).
2. When device boots, it changes its state from `offline` to `online`, but a different process checks periodically if state is `offline` or `online` for current device and **others** on the network.
3. it is not same as when subscribing to a retained topic, that you get the state at that specific time.
4. Storing chage of state in a variable, is one way to do it, but is there a different way ?

Comment: Sorry, question edited.

Comment: @jsotola - I'm subscribed for specific topic, but how I actively ( on demand -  inside an `if` statement ), verify that my retained state is `online` or `offline` ?

Comment: @Guy.D, when you say: "it is not same as when subscribing to a retained topic, that you get the state at that specific time." what do you mean?  If the publisher and the broker were on line all the time and the subscriber just came on line, the retained Node-RED message (topic and payload) would be  the last message sent from the publisher.

Answer (score 1):

Once a message has passed through an [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) [broker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker) there is not a way to retrieve it from the broker.

Consider instead deciding upon the action at the time the message is received by the subscriber.  If this decision needs to be made at a later time consider storing the state in the of the payload of the message on the subscriber.

Also consider running [Node-RED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node-RED).  If the platform running the MQTT broker can support Node-RED (such as a Raspberry Pi), it turns out to be convenient to run both on the same computer.  Node-RED contains nodes (graphical programming blocks) which can [subscribe to and publish to MQTT topics](https://cookbook.nodered.org/mqtt/connect-to-broker).  By connecting other nodes to these, the topic and payload can be manipulated.  Of interest is an option within the Output MQTT node.  Here you can select Retain True.  [This page](https://cookbook.nodered.org/mqtt/publish-retained-message) explains how this option works:

> Once you have sent a retained message to a topic, all subscribers will
>   receive that message when they subscribe.
>
> To clear a previously retained topic from the broker, send a blank
>   message to that topic with the retain flag set.

Comment: This is the only way I had in mind ( storing state change in a specific variable ), but I was hoping there is a better way.

Comment: Please edit your question: 1) Add your comment in which you make it clear why you want to retrieve old MQTT topics.  2) Tell us what you are running your MQTT broker on.  3) What you will do with the on-line / off-line information.  As there are additional tools that work well with MQTT that may apply to your situation.

Comment: thank you. edited

Comment: @Guy.D, I need to go off line for a while.  If you do edit your question to make it better - I am going to assume you are using a normal personal computer for the MQTT broker.  That platform likely will support Node-RED a graphical programming language designed to process MQTT topics which uses a web page interface.  It will take some time to get used to - so we need to make a decision, based on your edited question, if it is worth the effort to install and learn.

Comment: thank you, did you see Q was edited with information asked?

Comment: Yes, it will be an effort, but I think installing and learning Node-RED will solve your problems.  And perhaps you can process your MQTT message payloads partly on Node-RED simplifying the code on your MQTT Arduino clients.

Comment: By the way- updating status to offline ( generated by lastwill) won’t update the specified variable